# How to select records which do not have rows with dates falling in the current week

Tags: sql, linq, t-sql

I'm moving a linq query to ado and can't seem to get the correct syntax for achieving my desired results.

[image]
I have a simple setup where user's have associated actions. I want to select users that are not following me and have had no action records on file for the current week.

Here is the equivalent linq query I'm trying to convert (note these are different table names but with the same exact schema)

```
var users = context.IG_Cats_Users.Where(p => p.IsFollowing == false
                                                             & p.IsRequested == false &
                                                             !p.IG_Cat_Actions.Any(
                                                                 a =>
                                                                     DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Date) >=
                                                                     first.Date
                                                                     &
                                                                     DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Date) <=
                                                                     last.Date))
                    .Take(numOfUsers);
```

Here is my query so far

```
 var qry = "SELECT Id FROM Users "
            + "INNER JOIN Actions ON Users.Id = Actions.UserId "
            + "WHERE Users.IsFollowing = 0 AND Users.IsRequested = 0 AND IF NOT EXISTS ("
```

I figured I'd try `IF NOT EXISTS` [EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)
but per every example they run a subquery in the clause. I want to make sure any actions being searched are associated with the user from the first part of the query but I can't figure out how to work it out in TSQL

**EDIT**
Concerning the dates: I already have the two date values being created in code which I am passing to the function. It's computed in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT u.Id
FROM Users u
WHERE u.IsFollowing = 0 AND u.IsRequested = 0 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Actions a
                  WHERE u.Id = a.UserId
                 );
```

Comment: Okay so the way to associate the two queries then is by aliasing the actual tables. Got it!